# spacing between buttons

Tags: android, android-layout

Sorry as  this is a repeated question , but posting Is necessary as  everyone  would have different setups

Here is my xml file .... Please suggest to bring proper spacing between the three buttons , Any further suggestions  would be  appreciated

**MainMenu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mainbackground"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
    android:paddingRight="2dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/maintitle">
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BtnDisplay"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dip"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
            android:text="@string/mem_sig_display"
            android:textColor="#315683"
            android:textSize="30px" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BtnSlave"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:text="@string/mes_mod_linked"
        android:textColor="#315683"
        android:textSize="30px" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Histbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:text="@string/History"
        android:textColor="#315683"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried the margins and padding but seems like am not able to detect the right measurements required

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of how it appears now, and also describe (or even better post a mock up screen shot) of what "proper spacing between the three buttons" means to you?

Comment: Suggest what? `proper spacing` isn't a defined specification. We cannot look up `proper spacing` and guide you to achieve `it`.

Comment: As said post a screenshot and some more details can be given, but typical guide states `16dp`

Answer (score 0):

Best way to deal with multiple buttons in linear layout is by using

> weight property

. Also for spacing use **padding or margin** (carefully use one of them as padding is between components and margin is with refernce to boundaries).

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="2dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BtnDisplay"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#315683"
            android:textSize="30px" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BtnSlave"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#315683"
            android:textSize="30px" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Histbutton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#315683"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```